# How to use Request.UrlReferrer in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, url

I have two aspx web pages. In the first one I have this code:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Response.Redirect("~/Code.aspx")
End Sub
```

Now in the Code.aspx page I have this code:

```
Label1.Text = Request.UrlReferrer.ToString
```

I want the label show the first page URl, but there is a runtime ERROR.How to fix this? thanks

This is the error message: `Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: `Request.UrlReferrer` is probably `null` hence you get a `NullReferenceException` when trying to access it. Check for `null`. On a side note: `UrlReferrer` will always be `null` when using `Response.Redirect`

Comment: I posted the Error Message. Thanks Sani, so how it will show the reffered URL? What should I use instead of Response.Redirect?

Comment: `UrlReferrer` will contain information of the previous `Url` only when the client (i.e. browser) sends it. You cannot programmatically set it. If the user types in the url into the browser then there will be no `UrlReferrer`. Only when the user clicks a link will the `UrlReferrer` be sent from the client. The client also has the choice of never sending the `UrlReferrer` at all. It all depends on the client/browser. `UrlReferrer` should not be trusted at any time to be valid either. It can be spoofed.

Comment: Ok. I wanted to disable the user access to my web page by pasting the URL in the browser bar. I have used response.redirect method in the first page. Is there any way I could use?

Comment: To accomplish your requirements you should implement `authentication`. I.e. have the users login to you site with user/password. As I said you should never ever trust `UrlReferrer` to be valid.

Comment: Another solution would be to set a cookie but this would break the site for users who do not allow cookies to be set. You can also use a cookieless session to keep a track of a session. See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479314.aspx).

Comment: I think there is a way to disable the user access to a special web page by editing web.config file. I know the session but it is not a trusted way too. because the user may open the first page and the session will be saved and then the secound page will be opened easily. Am I wrong?

Comment: @user3724490 There are plenty of ways to disable access to specific pages but that is not what is requested here.

Answer (score -1):

Take the redirect out of the page load and put it on a link or something other than a response.redirect. Then try something like this in your code to make sure it's not null:

```
if(Request.UrlReferrer != null)
{ 
    Label1.Text = Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();
}
else
{
    Label1.Text = "No URL referrer";
}
```

Sorry just noticed you're using VB.net, the code is easy enough to change though and the theory is the same.

If you require the response.redirect I suppose a cookie based solution would work but seems a little involved for such a basic requirement.

Comment: In this case `Label1.Text` will always be set to `No URL referrer`.

Comment: `Request.UrlReferrer` will not be set when using `Response.Redirect`. See my comments in the OP.